# provide API to mobile app with JWT token

Tags: ios, security, ssl, oauth, jwt

I am a developing an Rest API in spring boot and it has to be consumed by an IOS Application.I have implemented JWT token with Oaut 2.0 as security and my web server is having SSL.So the call will be made by

```
https://server:port//dataurl
```

with the header as the token. My question is since My web Server is having SSL so the connection channel will be secured (because the token should be passed in a secure channel ) or do the client side (IOS App) should also have to implement SSL Certificate. I am a having a little confusion about how the SSL channel communication. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link has a nice graph about how SSL works.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660_.htm

You can have a look of AFNetworking, no matter you want to use it or not.
In particular, have a look of AFSecurityPolicy.h and how it is used in AFURLSessionManager.m. That could be a good start point.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Correct me if I am wrong so the mobile app side also should have the SSL Certificate

Comment: But since the server side has the SSL certificate and I am using jwt token for the authorization will be that good enough or should I install the SSLcertificate on the app side as well.

Comment: This link talks about ssl certificate chain, reckon it will give you a clearer picture of what certificates needs to be installed on iOS devices. https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/. This link has installed certificates on iOS 10. https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207177

Comment: JWT token is used for authentication and SSL certificate is used for establishing trust and data encryption between client and server. Different purposes.

Comment: Mobile app should have the root certificate of the CA authority who issued server SSL certificate, So that mobile app can verify server SSL certificate. If you go to keychain app on your Mac, there is a system root option, same thing. The documentation of this method - SecTrustEvaluate also helps.